# Upgrading to Windows 8 Pro from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, installation, upgrade

Weird, I know, but bear with me here, please.

I've been assembling a PC for sometime now, piece by piece. A friend gave me a gift for it: Windows 8 Pro (that's what it says on the box).

I was initially skeptical at first, as I know that Pro editions don't come for cheap (my friend is cheap), but I installed it anyway.

I got past the installation no problem, and got everything setup. However, upon trying to activate Windows (Action Center notification), it says my product key can is only used for upgrading, not clean installs. (There really should be a safeguard against this).

Huh. So it appears he gave me an upgrade, as opposed to a full OS. I obviously need to buy an OS first. Which raises the following questions:

- Will there be any restrictions as to what *OS I need to install first*? I have a (what it says on the top of the box) `Windows 8 Pro 32/64 Bit Eng Intl VUP DVD`. The only things shops sell are Windows 8.1 OEM and 8.1 OEM medialess (no idea what that means). Can I use those? Would there be any conflicts I have to watch out for (single language, etc.)
- Would there be any repercussions to reformatting the drive Windows 8 Pro resides on, and installing the above Windows version? Can I still use the Win 8 Pro product keys? I've heard horror stories of PKs getting invalidated, and having to call Microsoft or something - not ideal when you're on the other side of the world.
- Microsoft website says that Windows 8 can upgrade to Windows 8 Pro via the Add Features option, and a Windows 8 Pro **Pack** - is that the same as what I have?

Thanks.

Comment: No;  It sounds like he gave you a `Windows 8.0 Professional` *Upgrade* license, if you were told, it can only upgrade existing installations.  This cannot be used to upgrade an existing Windows 8.1 "Core" installation, you cannot downgrade back to Windows 8.0, without reinstalling your operating system.

Comment: Yikes. That's what I feared. It appears I'll have to find myself a Windows 8 license. Assuming there is, are there any other restrictions I should be aware of?

Comment: You should be able to do, select the option, to keep nothing if you start the installation process from within Windows.  You just can't keep your personal files if you do that.  Why are you going back to 8.0 exactly?  Windows 8.1 does not have a Upgrade license, all retail licenses, have no such restriction are all System Builder licenses. What you want is the *8.1 Pro Pack*

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand exactly what you're saying. I'm not going back to Windows 8 per se. I have a `Windows 8 Pro`. From your first comment, it appears I can NOT use it to upgrade a `Windows 8.1 Core`, so I'm going to find a `Windows 8`, I just don't know what edition.